# Fancyhdr, chaptermark and table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using fancyhdr for editing the header of my document.
I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\small\bfseries\leftmark\quad\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\markboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}

\listoftables
\markboth{\listtablename}{\listtablename}

\listoffigures
\markboth{\listfigurename}{\listfigurename}

\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

which correctly display chapter number, chapter name (in lower case), page number and a line below, in the top right corner of each page, except the first of each chapter.
I only have an issue with the table of contents: the second page show "INDEX ii", while the third (correctly) show "Index iii".
Why I have this inconsistency?

Comment: I'm not sure I can reproduce your problem here. I just added some dummy chapters and a `\tableofcontents`, and I get `CONTENTS <page#>` in the header on each page of the table of contents. How do you issue your table of contents? Do you override the default chapter marks?

Comment: Yes, I redefined the default chapter mark in the two last line of the above code.

Comment: ... but I took your complete code above and I can't reproduce your problem. What else did you change?

Comment: Please post a **complete** small document demonstrating your issue so that people can reproduce. This is much more useful than a mere code fragment (as this case illustrates well). Also, do you really want both `oneside` and `openright`? The latter only seems to make sense for `twoside`.

Comment: I, too, cannot reproduce your specific issue.  Consider that `\chaptermark` doesn't get called for the contents section.  You can manually adjust the `leftmark` for the contents with something like `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\markboth{\contentsname}{}}`.

Comment: I posted a complete document with my issue. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still can't reproduce your problem as you've stated it. I'm now extrapolating what you might be trying to do: I'm assuming you're using a manual `\markboth` command for the table of contents, such as something similar to:

```
\tableofcontents
\markboth{Index}{}
```

and then the `\markboth` command only takes effect on the last page of the table of contents, as one can expect.

So, not sure now if I'm answering your question, but speculating: if you don't want the header to be upper cased, you can use the following code:

```
{
  \renewcommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{#1}
  \tableofcontents
}
```

LaTeX uses `\MakeUppercase` when defining the marks for e.g. the table of contents (you can check in `book.cls` source), so the `\renewcommand` makes it now ineffective. The braces ensure that `\MakeUppercase` will continue to behave normally in the rest of the document.

Also, with the `book` document class, I get `Contents` in the header, not `Index` as you describe. If you want to change that, you can use

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{Index}
```

But I'd expect `Index` is usually rather used for a [lookup index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28publishing%29) at the end of the book, with keywords and pages where those terms appear.

Comment: I posted a complete document with my issue. As you speculated, I'm probably misusing the markboth command, which has effect on the last page only (and not on all the page, as I though).

Comment: @Andrea The `\markboth` command seems to be issued _after_ the table of contents is generated, so it only affects the last page (the one that's not completed yet). LaTeX itself calls `\markboth` inside the `\tableofcontents` command with arguments `\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}` (see `book.cls`: `\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}` with `\@mkboth` alias of `\markboth`), so that's why I suggest you redefine `\MakeUppercase` to be ineffective for when LaTeX will call it from `\tableofcontents`. (But there may be other ways to achieve this.)